# Is there any other way to access a class, except by Id?

Tags: class, forms, extjs, load, extjs4

How else could i access this class, i need my dynamic ID for something else... Normally if this was // var something = Ext.create(... i would do something.getForm().load...)???

```
Ext.define('app.winKontakt',{
    extend:'Ext.form.Panel',
    closable:true,
    id:"myId",    <------------------------------------------ID
    waitMsgTarget: true,
    border:false,
    defaults: {
    anchor: '30%',
    padding:10
    },
    reader : Ext.create('Ext.data.reader.Json', {
        model: 'app.contact',
        record : 'contact',
        successProperty: '@success'
    }),


    ...

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Load',
        handler: function(){

            winId = Ext.getCmp("myId");    <--------------GET

            winId.getForm().load({    <---------------EXECUTE
                url: 'app/new.json',
                waitMsg: 'Loading...',
                method:"GET"
            });
        }

     ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just started with ExtJS, so there may be a better practices.

You can assign an itemId to the component and use [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) to get it.

```
Ext.define('app.view.contact.Form', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
  itemId: 'myId',

  buttons: [{
    text: 'Load',
    handler: function(){
      Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myId').getForm().load({...});
    }
  }]
})
```

Another options is to use the [up()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-up) function from AbstractComponent to get the enclosing form.

```
Ext.define('app.view.contact.Form', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

  buttons: [{
    text: 'Load',
    handler: function(){
      this.up('form').load({...});
    }
  }]
})
```

I normally don't put any code in the view definition, instead I use the [control()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-control) function within a Ext.app.Controller to have proper MVC separation:

```
Ext.define('app.controller.Contacts', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  views: ['app.view.contact.Form'],

  init: function() {
    this.control({
      'button[action=load]': {
        click: this.loadForm
      }
    })
  }

  loadFrom: function() {...}
})

Ext.define('app.view.contact.Form', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

  buttons: [{
    text: 'Load',
    action: 'load'
  }]
})
```

In this small example it looks quite like some overhead, but with a larger codebase the control function is quite handy to understand the events sent from a complex view to the controller.

Comment: no, this isnt working, but thanks. I think I need to somehow get class name (app.winKontakt) and then load into it.

Comment: Sorry @Ingol, I forgot to use a # to reference an item id. I updated the answer and added two more possibilities.

Comment: yes, this.up('form') works, Also just starting, so MVC is definitely next step, thank you so much!